# Calculating electric reduction(or oxidation) potential for complex ion formation equation?

Tags: equilibrium, coordination-compounds, nernst-equation

I would like to calculate the standard electric potential($E°$) for the following equation.

$$\ce{Pt^{2+}(aq) + 4Cl-(aq) → [PtCl4]^{2-}(aq)}$$

$K_f = \pu{1.0 * 10^16}, T =\pu{ 298K}$

I figured out

$ΔG° = -nFE° = -RT\ln K$.

So, $E° = (\frac{RT}{nF})\ln K = (\frac{0.06}{n})\ln K (\text{approximated }\frac{RT}{F} = 0.06)$.

However, I'm having trouble finding $n$, or the number of moles of electrons transferred.

I'm not sure whether electrons are transferred in an complex ion formation equation.

Could you please help me with this confusion?